# database index in Active Record Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

let's imagine this situation.I have a `article` model and a `sort` model,and they have a one-to-many association.

the `article` migration is :

```
create_table :articles do |t|
  t.string :title      
  t.string :content
  t.belongs_to :sort

  t.timestamps
end
```

the `sort` migration is :

```
create_table :sorts do |t|
    t.string :title  

    t.timestamps
end
```

so the `article` will be added a filed named `sort_id`.

now,I want to add an index on the filed `sort_id` in table `articles`.

whether I can realize as follow:

```
   add_index :articles, :sort, :unique => true
```

or

```
  add_index :articles, :sort_id, :unique => true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_index :articles, :sort_id, :unique => true
```